# CSS vh will not take into account the full height of the website design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, user-experience

I'm trying to build a design portfolio with html & CSS using vh and vw to give the design a limited degree of responsiveness, but whenever I use the appropriate vh values based on percentages I've found, the command only takes in to account what is actively being viewed in the screen, not the entire of the design. The problem I'm having is located in the "index.css file"

This is what it's supposed to look like:

[image]

https://github.com/kylep34/Portolio The github, if anyone wants to take a look would be greatly appreciated.

Also, please keep in mind, I'm just a beginning UX Designer

Comment: Thats what its supposed to do, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to provide more information here.

Comment: To clarify vh is viewport height. it represents 1 % of the height of the visible page.